# Count equality operator

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array and want to use Array#count to count #3:

```
[1,2,2,3,3,3,3.0,3.0].count(3) #>5
```

It results in 5 instead of 3.In the docs,it indicates count uses `==` for equality but i wanted to use `eql?` instead of `==`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[1,2,2,3,3,3,3.0,3.0].select { |e| e.eql? 3 }
#⇒ [
#  [0] 3,
#  [1] 3,
#  [2] 3
# ]
```

Respectively,

```
[1,2,2,3,3,3,3.0,3.0].count { |e| e.eql? 3 }
#⇒ 3
```

will return a count.

Comment: wanted to use Array#count,since it can take a block

Comment: `count` accepts a block, as well. I have the answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
[1,2,2,3,3,3,3.0,3.0].count { |e| e.eql? 3 }
=> 3
```